# Set specific group of Django user as celery worker

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-middleware

I need to make a specific group of Django user(group : delivery person) as celery worker. Whenever any registered django user from that specific group logs in, they can pick task from the celery queue and complete. As soon as one user completes a task, it must be dequeued from the queue and asynchronously it should not be visible to the next logged in user from that group.

Comment: You can't apply absolute celery in such case, you need to put these task in database table's queue and then apply celery and dequeue those from table's row / column flag. Even I would suggest don't use celery at all in your case that will also work.

Comment: Ok.. I'm new with Django, so was wondering if I could make a user as celery worker

Answer (score 1):

As @Anup Yadav noted, Celery is not a good fit for this use case. Storing your tasks in the database works fine, you just have to lock the row using `select_for_update` to ensure that a task can't be picked twice. Something like this should work:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def pick_task():
    """
    Selects a task and marks it as unavailable.

    Returns Task or None, if no Task is available.
    """  
    task = Task.objects.select_for_update().filter(is_available=True).first()
    if task is not None:
        task.is_available = False
        task.save()
    return task
```

Checking if the user has the right group would be done in the view. Note that `pick_task` should probably be a method of a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

Comment: I will try this way. For making it asynchronous across all users I possibly can use websockets.

Comment: what if a user declines a task, and I set is_available back to True but it must not be visible to him? I mean, whever a user declines a task it will be available for other users to accept the task but not for the specific user whoever declined it.

Comment: You have to store that information somewhere. The easiest way would probably be a field `rejected_by = models.ManyToMany(get_user_model())`, but if this is the best way depends on your exact requirements. This really should be a separate question.